# Исключение в деструкторе

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Всем доброго времени суток. У меня есть класс представляющий собой список. При попытке вызова деструктора выпадает исключение, но тлько если для intList был вызван метод Add. Никак не могу понять в чем дело. Вот код:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    template <class T>
    class List {
    static const int defaultCapacity = 20;
    static const int defaultSize = 0;

    unsigned int capacity;
    unsigned int size;
    T* list;

    public:
        List() : capacity(defaultCapacity), size(defaultSize)
        {
            list = new T[size];
        }

        ~List()
        {
            delete[] list;
        }

        void Add(const T& item)
        {           
            if(size < capacity)
                list[size++] = item;
            else 
            {
                auto tmp = list;
                delete[] list;
                list = new T[capacity *= 2];
                memcpy(list, tmp, sizeof(list) * sizeof(T));
                size++;
            }
        }
};

int main()
{
    auto intList = new List<int>();
    intList->Add(3); // без этой строки исключения нет  
    delete intList;
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: IMHO  Вам стоит **внимательно** посмотреть вот на это

    ....
    defaultSize = 0;
    .....
    T* list;
  
    public:
        List() : ... , size(defaultSize)
        {
            list = new T[size];  
    .....

Вот на **`new T[size]`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Доброго времени суток! 
Проблема в строчках

```
auto tmp = list;
delete[] list;
```

Дело в том, что у вас неявно вызывается конструктор копирования и во временную переменную вы копируете указатель `T *list`, таким образом у Вас получается два указателя указывающих на одну и ту же область памяти. Когда вызывается деструктор, то уже очищенную область памяти вы пытаетесь удалиться повторно, что и вызывает ошибку. Я бы на вашем месте воспользовался функцией realloc или использовал бы класс std::list<T> из библиотеки STL, что наиболее удачно в Вашем случае.

Comment: да но дело в том что в приведенном примере до этих строк дело ни разу не доходит так как этот код выполняется только если size >= capacity, а здесь этого ни разу не происходит

Comment: Да, вы правы - невнимательно посмотрел) Но у Вас есть еще проблема: как Вам удалось создать массив из нуля элементов?  
list = new T[size]; // size = 0!
Возможно вы имели в виду это:
list = new T[capacity]; 
?

Comment: спасибо) именно в этом было дело)))